# Can not find last row on a separate worksheet in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working on a macro and I had it working 100% like I wanted, but when I went to move the control group to a different sheet, I've started getting all sorts of problems. Here is the code:

```
Sub Duplicate_Count()

'Diclare Variables
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim value1 As String
Dim value2 As String
Dim counter As Long
Dim startRange As Long
Dim endRange As Long
Dim inColumn As String
Dim outColumn As String
Dim color As Long
counter = 0
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim controlSht As Worksheet
Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set controlSht = Worksheets("Duplicate Check")

'Find the last used row in column L
LastRow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row

'set default ranges
startRange = 2
endRange = LastRow - 1
inColumn = "L"
outColumn = "N"

'check for user inputs
If controlSht.Cells(8, "B") <> "" Then
    startRange = controlSht.Cells(8, "B")
End If
If controlSht.Cells(8, "C") <> "" Then
    endRange = controlSht.Cells(8, "C")
End If
If controlSht.Cells(11, "C") <> "" Then
    Column = controlSht.Cells(11, "C")
End If
If controlSht.Cells(14, "C") <> "" Then
    Column = controlSht.Cells(14, "C")
End If
color = controlSht.Cells(17, "C").Interior.color

'Search down row for duplicates
Dim i As Long

For i = startRange To endRange

    'Sets value1 and value2 to be compared
    value1 = sht.Cells(i, inColumn).Value
    value2 = sht.Cells(i + 1, inColumn).Value

    'If values are not diferent then counter will not increment
    counter = 1

    Do While value1 = value2
        sht.Cells(i, inColumn).Interior.color = color
        sht.Cells(i + counter, inColumn).Interior.color = color
        counter = counter + 1
        value2 = sht.Cells(i + counter, inColumn).Value
    Loop

    'Ouput the number of duplicates on last duplicates row
    If counter <> 1 Then
        sht.Cells(i + counter - 1, outColumn) = counter
        i = i + counter - 1
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

This is my first program so I apologize for all the mistakes. This code does exactly what I want except for finding the last row if there is no user input. It always says the last row is 1, when it should be 110460. I'm not sure if it's grabbing from the wrong sheet or if there is an error in my logic.

Comment: Your comment in the code says you are looking in column A but in the code you are looking in column L, are you sure you are looking in the correct column?

Comment: Same as @ScottCraner said. Also you already defined your worksheet(Sheet1), so you can use `LastRow = sht.Cells.....` Besides that it is good to explicitly reference the workbook you are working in. So that things don't get mixed up when having multiple workbooks open.

Comment: yes sorry that comment is wrong, it is column L. and it is redundant because i was just trying to get it to work:P

Comment: Could you paste a screenshot of your worksheet into the question please.  It makes no sense that changing your code to use column K instead of L would resolve the issue, when you have commented that column K is completely empty.  (I'm just wondering whether column K & L have been merged, so K looks empty but isn't, and L looks used but is empty.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the "L" to an 11, and it all seems to work now. Why it wants it this way i have no clue, but it works.

Comment: Column "L" is column 12, not 11.  (The letter for column 11 is "K")

Comment: That's what i thought, but k is empty on my sheet so 11 shouldn't work, yet it does....

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy to fix by just Activating the sheet first.  I can't recall the exact syntax but since you tagged this macros just record a macro, then select a sheet and click on it somewhere.  Then open up the macro it will say something like Sheets("sheet name".Activate.  Or Sheets("sheet name").Select.  Repeat that for each worksheet you want to run the macro on.  To clarify, each time your macro finds the last row on 1 sheet, then you Activate or Select the next worksheet and find the last row again.  Suppose this is being called in a loop through list of worksheet names.

Comment: im not sure i understand what you mean by this?

Comment: @Josh if you don't know how to record a macro you can just type either of those lines above before your code finds the last row -I checked the syntax is right.

Comment: Okay so i tried both of those ways and neither worked, but i did change the "L" to 11, and now it works. Why it wasn't working with the letter i have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

I always do it like this.

```
Sub FindingLastRow()

'PURPOSE: Different ways to find the last row number of a range
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Ctrl + Shift + End
  LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Using UsedRange
  sht.UsedRange 'Refresh UsedRange
  LastRow = sht.UsedRange.Rows(sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

'Using Table Range
  LastRow = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Rows.Count

'Using Named Range
  LastRow = sht.Range("MyNamedRange").Rows.Count

'Ctrl + Shift + Down (Range should be first cell in data set)
  LastRow = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

End Sub
```

https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba